# Fragment's onActivityCreated() is called after onDestroy() of Activity

Tags: android-fragments, android

Today I noticed a strange behavior in my application.

It happens when I stop my application using Devices view from Eclipse. Can someone explain it?

Why is `onActivityCreated()` of `Fragment` called even when `Activity` is already destroyed?
`MyHomeActivity` contains two `Fragment`s and similar log is generated for both.

Here I am pasting logs for one `Fragment`. 
`NullPointerException` is a secondary problem.

I am surprised why `onActivityCreated()` is called when the call stack was initiated from `onDestroy()` of `MyHomeActivity`?

```
03-05 12:31:21.414: W/System.err(5638): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-05 12:31:21.421: W/System.err(5638):     at **MyListViewFrag.onActivityCreated**(BuddyListViewFrag.java:85)
03-05 12:31:21.421: W/System.err(5638):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1468)
03-05 12:31:21.421: W/System.err(5638):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:931)
03-05 12:31:21.421: W/System.err(5638):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
03-05 12:31:21.421: W/System.err(5638):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1070)
03-05 12:31:21.421: W/System.err(5638):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchReallyStop(FragmentManager.java:1888)
03-05 12:31:21.421: W/System.err(5638):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onReallyStop(FragmentActivity.java:787)
03-05 12:31:21.421: W/System.err(5638):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.doReallyStop(FragmentActivity.java:764)
03-05 12:31:21.421: W/System.err(5638):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onDestroy(FragmentActivity.java:322)
03-05 12:31:21.421: W/System.err(5638):     at MyFragmentActivity.onDestroy(RbrFragmentActivity.java:57)
03-05 12:31:21.421: W/System.err(5638):     at **MyHomeActivity.onDestroy**(MyHomeActivity.java:254)
03-05 12:31:21.421: W/System.err(5638):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
03-05 12:31:21.421: W/System.err(5638):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:2694)
03-05 12:31:21.421: W/System.err(5638):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-05 12:31:21.421: W/System.err(5638):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:968)
03-05 12:31:21.421: W/System.err(5638):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-05 12:31:21.421: W/System.err(5638):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-05 12:31:21.421: W/System.err(5638):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
03-05 12:31:21.429: W/System.err(5638):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-05 12:31:21.429: W/System.err(5638):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-05 12:31:21.429: W/System.err(5638):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
03-05 12:31:21.429: W/System.err(5638):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
03-05 12:31:21.429: W/System.err(5638):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am using support library for providing `Fragment`s to pre-HoneyComb devices, if that makes any difference.

Comment: You seem to override the `onDestroy` callback. What are you doing there?

Comment: nothing just calling super.OnDestroy()

Comment: I just noticed this same behavior on my 4.2 emulator. Did you find anymore info?

Comment: @NickCampion this is strange behavior of Android. I am yet to find the reason behind this. Please do share if you get the logic.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After some testing and reviewing [FragmentManager.moveToState](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.java?av=f), I believe that when the `Fragment` is being handled by a `FragmentPagerAdapter`, it is unavoidable that a `Fragment` which was previously coalesced into savedState (as part of the process of stopping the app before you kill the process from the DDMS tab in eclipse), must first be "created" (in the terminology of `FragmentManager`) before it can be destroyed.

This may actually be an unintended consequence of the process of rebuilding the fragments from saved state. When the `FragmentActivity` is executing `onCreate` and `finish()` is called, the intention is that the `FragmentActivity` stops setting up and exits. The visual experience is that this occurs, but it seems like the `FragmentManager` takes it on itsself to continue the lifecycle for previously existing `Fragment`s, albiet with some short cuts. This process seems to execute the lifecycle methods up to `onActivityCreated` and then execute `onDestroy` and `onDetach`, skipping those in between.

The best way to handle this appears to be to address the secondary issues (in this case, your NPE) caused by this startup. It seems like there would be room to optimize this out of the `Fragment` lifecycle, but with the r12 support library, the situation appears to be a consequence of the design.

Comment: I have also noticed exactly same behavior. However I was waiting for an answer which can put all the points together. Thanks a lot this can be really helpful for others and Yes, I have already solved that NPE and that solved this strange issue. This is certainly not expected from Android guys...

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. A couple years later, this logic still seems to be same, unfortunately.